# FTB Ultimate Server constantly giving "can't keep up!" errors

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am looking for some tips for getting a FTB Ultimate server server up to speed. I constantly get the "Can't Keep Up" messages.

I am running a FTB ultimate 1.1.2 server on Windows 2008 R2, with an AMD FX 4170 Quad-Core @ 4.20 GHZ and 8 GB of RAM. The server itself is running on a dedicated WD Black SATA 3 drive. This drive is currently only in use by the FTB server.

There are only two of us on the server at the moment, and I am on the same local network. Both of us experience jerkiness and general lag. Lately my friend has been experiencing upwards of one minute just to open the crafting table.

There have been no changes to the FTB server aside from general changes to the GregTech and Advanced solar panel configs. The lag was happening before that as well.

I have noticed that at times the Minecraft server has worlds listed as having 5000+ chunks cached, or close to 2 GB of RAM allocated. The server generally is at 60-70% CPU usage.

My startup config is pretty basic, but is allowing a max of 5GB:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -Xms512M -Xmx5G -jar ftbserver.jar
```

I am currently running Java 64-bit, version 7 Update 25

Comment: Something on your server is eating processor cycles. 2GB is way, way too much for 2 users. Any complex redstone? Chunkloaders near mob grinders? Do you use Linkbooks a lot? Anything in general that is constantly running?

Comment: Oh! Also, definitely reduce your 5GB down to 3GB or 2GB. That's way too much. Windows wants to keep about 4GB to itself, so Java reserving 5GB = 9GB. That means lots of your memory is unnecessarily going through a disk-based pagefile cache.

Comment: But windows is showing only 4.19GB of used ram. It rarely seems like the system is struggling for ram. I can reduce it, but I am not confident it will help. There are a couple of chunk loaders, but most of the time we are in those areas anyway, so the chunks would be loaded. We originally were operating in Yogcraft, and the overall lag was worse, so we upgrade the server to FTB ultimate and noticed some improvement and less redstone related crashes. I wouldnt say we are using complex redstone, but there are a few things connected to timers, with transposers and the like.

Comment: I run a server for 10 users on 2G max (and it's never needed it all). Whatever the problem is, giving it more RAM is just hiding the problem and reducing it to more normal amount is still advisable.

Comment: I understand that the amount of ram is overkill. I do not think increasing the ram is hiding the true problem. If anything, if decreasing the ram were to make the server give lag due to virtual ram swapping to the disk, that would mask the original problem. Since it would appear the server rarely states it is using over 1.8 GB of memory I will decrease it from 5G to 3G as per your suggestion and see if anything changes.

Comment: Change has been made. Normally while the FTB Ultimate server is running, the server is using 60-70% CPU, and around 4.2 GB of ram. When i stop the FTB server, it is roughly 1% cpu utilization and 2GB ram. When I first start the FTB back up, i notice the minecraft console says roughly 200-300MB of ram are in use, but then it later shoots up to the 1.8GB. the CPU utilzation seems to be constantly at 60-70% utilzation when FTB is running...regardless of when.

Comment: Sounds like you should have enough resources.  Have you tried creating a brand new map on the server, and seeing if the CPU usage declines?  If so, then something in your map is causing minecraft to use a lot of CPU, you can remove your chunk loaders one at a time and unload the chunks to find the cause.

Comment: Generally the amount of processing required on a server scales with the number of chunks loaded - the number of users is largely irrelevant except as an indirect proxy to how many chunks are generally loaded at once.  Do you know how many chunks are actively loaded on the server while it is running?  This is always a helpful read: http://www.sk89q.com/2013/03/improving-your-minecraft-servers-performance/

Comment: I am going to try closing the current FTB server and opening a newly downloaded one to see how the CPU usage is compared to the original...

Comment: Ok, it would appear even with a brand new test world the CPU usage seems to spike up from 1 % when FTB is off, up to roughly 60-65% when it is on.

I have seen other suggestions saying stuff like getting the Java SDK instead of the normal java and doing things like:
setting garbage collection to be multithreaded
Use SSE4 cpu instructions
possibly set java itself to be multithreaded

while I have not confirmed any of these, at quick glance it would appear java is running multithreaded as all 4 cores of my CPU show usage spikes when I start it up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft tech support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a thread on the FTB forum, and while some of the info may be contradictory or misinformation, i did see they were using a special startup config. While I am not entirely postive of what this does....what I can (hopefully) deduce from it is that it is enabling the FTB server to use SS4 cpu instructions and modifying how garbage collection is ran. After running the server with this config, within minutes the "tick lag" on the server disappeared, everything moved very smoothly.... and best of all, CPU usage went from 70% to 14% even with several chunk loaders and a quarry.

Thread found: http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/how-to-make-an-efficient-server.5525/

Startup config used:

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -server -Xincgc -Xmx3072M -Xms1024M -Xmn512M -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=2048 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xnoclassgc -oss4M -ss4M -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=90 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:UseSSE=4 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -cp "ftbserver.jar" -jar "ftbserver.jar"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (similar to the one I made for use on my server. But I run 16GB so I allocate 6GB to my minecraft server.  I've set yours to 4GB as that should be plenty for 2-16 players.. maybe even more)

```
java -server -DJINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:UseSSE=3 -Xmn2G -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -jar ftbserver.jar -nogui
```

Comment: Minecraft is not coded to take advantage of the extra abilities of SSE 4 this is software coding dependent. pointless to use.